# Outputting the binary of a file to a text editor

Tags: command-line, scripting, terminal, osx, xxd

I have read that you can use the terminal command `xxd -b` to see the binary of a file.  I used this command and it does show the binary but has non-binary listed to the left as line numbers and non-binary listed to the right.  I would like to simply read the binary of a file as the computer reads it, output that binary to a text editor and then go from the text editor back into binary. Any suggestions?  Can something similar be done using AppleScript?

Comment: `vim /path/to/file`?

Comment: Did you try `man xxd ` to see which options are available?also, what kind of manipulations, on what kind of files, do you have in mind?

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by "see the binary of a file"? What output are you expecting and what kind of file will you be reading?

Comment: Maybe check out [this post on hex editors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/827326/whats-a-good-hex-editor-viewer-for-the-mac)

Comment: No manipulations...what I would like to accomplish is to export the binary of a document or image file (really any type of file) as the computer reads it (in binary) to a text editor, then go in reverse and rename the file, then exporting the new file while still having the original.  So basically (Somefile --->binary--->text editor----->back to binary ----->rename Somefile to Somefile2---> export Somefile2 while keeping the original)  Basically, like going out of the way to make a simple copy of any file.

Comment: So are you looking for a `hexdump` stripped of the address on the left and original ASCII on the right? You can use `cut` or Bash substring syntax {a:start:end}

Comment: You guys will have to forgive me...I'm having to learn the mac terminal commands on my own as school only teaches the windows commands.  So, I'll have to research these other commands as well.

Answer (score 3):

> I would like to simply read the binary of a file as the computer reads it …

That's not really possible. The computer reads it as two different voltage levels somewhere, which you of course can't see. I suppose with a much slower computer (not the multi-GHz machines that are common today), you could attach a high-bandwidth oscilloscope and *almost* see/read it as the computer does. That's an electronics question, though, and surely not a useful answer. Ultimately, *any* way it's displayed on your monitor is an abstraction; there is simply no way to directly perceive the hundreds of billions if not trillions of voltage changes per second that the electronics actually deal in.

The normal way to edit binary data is in hexadecimal with a hex editor. Hexadecimal is used because it's easier for humans (far shorter) but still has a direct correspondence to the bits; each "nibble" of hex (0-9a-f) represents exactly 4 bits. The traditional way to display this is as done by `xxd`; it shows you practically everything you need to understand the binary file you're editing: on the left, where you are in the file (offset); on the right, what it is, if text (common enough in binary files); and in the middle, the raw binary data (presented in hexadecimal). `xxd` does similar for its binary mode, just using bits instead of hex.

If you really just want to cut that useful information off, `xxd` has an option for hex mode (`-p`), but not for binary mode. You can just use `cut` though:

```
$ echo 'Hello, world'  | xxd  -b | cut -c 11-63
01001000 01100101 01101100 01101100 01101111 00101100
00100000 01110111 01101111 01110010 01101100 01100100
00001010
```

Or if you really want no formatting, something like:

```
perl -nE 'print unpack("B*", $_); END { print "\n"; }'
```

(reversed by `perl -nE 'print pack("B*", $_);'`)

but if you really want to understand or edit binary data, a hex editor is by far your best bet for a general-purpose tool.

BTW: Your binary → text editor → binary is easy in hex mode; `xxd -r` does that. The perl snippets above will do it for binary:

```
$ echo 'Hello, world!' | perl -nE 'print unpack("B*", $_); END { print "\n"; }' | tee /dev/stderr | perl -nE 'print pack("B*", $_);'
0100100001100101011011000110110001101111001011000010000001110111011011110111001001101100011001000010000100001010
Hello, world!
```

I put the `tee` in there to show the bits being passed between them — note how utterly incomprehensible it is compared to `xxd`:

```
$ echo 'Hello, world!' | xxd | tee /dev/stderr | xxd -r
00000000: 4865 6c6c 6f2c 2077 6f72 6c64 210a       Hello, world!.
Hello, world!
```

Comment: So xxd -b | cut -c 11-63 cuts out the non-binary info from the xxd -b read leaving you with just binary.   So, other than using the perl script....there is no other way to go directly from binary that the computer reads to a text editor which displays the binary and back to the computer from the text editor as binary that the computer will read?  Like the computer converts binary into hex, I would like to convert binary into something like hex but not hex. Kinda like my own personal encryption.  you'll have to forgive, I'm just beginning prog. in school and all they teach is windows commands.

Comment: @Sand there are no doubt many other ways to do it, including no doubt a few lines of whatever programming language you're learning.